# Insert values from select query into variables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to insert into 2 variables values from select statement but I got an error which says:

> exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

I'm guessing that I need to put that data from select query into some table type?
But I need to process single record for the purpose of comparing to variable v_zmienna with v_zmienna2.

As you can see I try to somehow transfer data into v_zmienna and v_zmienna2 and after that compare that values.

Could anyone take a look and propose what's the best approach?

I need to use execute immediate and variables because I have Table1, Table2 tables as configure tables with names of tables which should be connected etc.

```
declare
c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;  
v_sourcepkcolumn varchar2(50);
v_sourcetable varchar2(50); 
v_targetfkcolumn varchar2(50); 
v_targetpkcolumn varchar2(50);    
v_targettable varchar2(50); 
v_sourcecolumn varchar2(50);  
v_targetcolumn varchar2(50); 
v_verificationdefid varchar2(50); 
v_zmienna varchar2(50); 
v_zmienna2 varchar2(50); 
v_random_number number;
begin
v_random_number := sequence1.nextval;
open c1 for select  sourcepkcolumn,
                    sourcetable,
                    targetfkcolumn,
                    targetpkcolumn,
                    targettable,
                    sourcecolumn,
                    targetcolumn,
                    ID
            from    table1,table2 where table1.ID=table2.ID;
loop
  fetch c1 into   v_sourcepkcolumn, 
                  v_sourcetable,    
                  v_targetfkcolumn, 
                  v_targetpkcolumn,   
                  v_targettable, 
                  v_sourcecolumn,    
                  v_targetcolumn, 
                  v_verificationdefid;
  exit when c1%notfound;   

  execute immediate 'select '||v_sourcetable||'.'||v_sourcecolumn||','||v_targettable||'.'||v_targetcolumn||' from '||v_sourcetable||','||v_targettable||' where '||
v_sourcetable||'.'||v_sourcepkcolumn||'='||v_targettable||'.'||v_targetfkcolumn into v_zmienna,v_zmienna2;

  if (v_zmienna=v_zmienna2) then
    execute immediate 'insert into table3 values ('||v_random_number||','||v_sourcecolumn||','||v_sourcepkcolumn||','||v_zmienna||',1,'||v_targetcolumn||','||v_targetpkcolumn||','||v_zmienna2||',timestamp,'||v_verificationdefid||')';
  else 
    execute immediate 'insert into table3 values ('||v_random_number||','||v_sourcepkcolumn||','||v_zmienna||',0,'||v_targetcolumn||','||v_targetpkcolumn||','||v_zmienna2||',timestamp,'||v_verificationdefid||')';
  end if;
end loop;
close c1;
end;
```

EDIT:

Output of

```
select  sourcepkcolumn,
                    sourcetable,
                    targetfkcolumn,
                    targetpkcolumn,
                    targettable,
                    sourcecolumn,
                    targetcolumn,
                  from    table1,table2 where table1.id=table2.id
```

Could looks:

```
PK_ACCOUNT,ACCOUNT,PK_ACC,ID,ACCOUNT2,NAME,NAME
```

That's the output from table1 and table2,

IMPORTANT: ACCOUNT AND ACCOUNT2 ARE VIEWS! that's no TABLES.

So now I wan't to compare account.name and account2.name from account VIEW with account2 VIEW on account.pk_account=account2.pk_acc.
Generally it works perfectly but sometimes (depends on oracle order) records in VIEW after join can be in other order.
For example:
Account:

```
PK_ACCOUNT   NAME
1             Eva
1             Adam
```

and 
Account2

```
PK_ACCOUNT  NAME
1            Adam
1            Eva
```

Why in VIEW different PK_ACCOUNT? Because I need to insert into Account and Account2 data from multiple tables. That's why records sometimes multiplies.

When procedure process one by one every records then takes it as divergent

Comment: In your `insert into table3` statements, you've got "timestamp" referenced. Did you mean "systimestamp"? Also, your second insert statement is only inserting 9 values, but your first insert is inserting 10. How many columns are there in table3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could just rewrite this as:

```
declare
  v_random_number number;
begin
  v_random_number := sequence1.nextval;
  for rec in (select  sourcepkcolumn,
                      sourcetable,
                      targetfkcolumn,
                      targetpkcolumn,
                      targettable,
                      sourcecolumn,
                      targetcolumn,
                      ID
              from    table1
                      inner join table2 on (table1.ID = table2.ID))
  loop
    execute immediate 'insert into table3 '||chr(10)|| -- where is the list of columns to insert into?!
                      ' select :v_random_number random_number,'||chr(10)||
                      '        :v_sourcecolumn source_col,'||chr(10)||
                      '        :v_sourcepkcolumn source_pk_col,'||chr(10)||
                      '        src.'||v_sourcecolumn||' source_col,'||chr(10)||
                      '        case when src.'||v_sourcecolumn||' = tgt.'||v_targetcolumn||' then 1 else 0 end one_or_zero'||chr(10)||
                      '        :v_targetcolumn target_col'||chr(10)||
                      '        :v_targetpkcolumn target_pk_col'||chr(10)||
                      '        tgt.'||v_targetcolumn||' target_col,'||chr(10)||
                      '        systimestamp tstamp,'||chr(10)||
                      '        :v_verificationdefid'||chr(10)||
                      ' from   '||v_sourcetable||' src'||chr(10)||
                      '        inner join '||v_targettable||' tgt on (src.'||v_sourcepkcolumn||' = tgt.'||v_targetfkcolumn||')'
                      using v_random_number,
                            rec.sourcecolumn,
                            rec.sourcepkcolumn,
                            rec.targetcolumn,
                            rec.targetpkcolumn,
                            rec.id;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

N.B. Untested. I guessed that your 2nd insert statement was missing the sourcecolumn, so I added that in.

Comment: Hello, thanks for Reply, I almost finished that, but now I have other issue. What if tables I defined In tables1,table2 after join return 2 records with same ID but in different order? For example   1 'Smth' 1 'Smthelse'   and second table return 1 'Smthelse' 1 'Smth'.  ( OF COURSE 1 as ID ) I can;t put order into (insert into statement), so is there any solution? If smth like that happened then procedure return 0 but should return 1 because that 2 records are the same..

Comment: Sounds like your join condition between table1 and table2 needs to be updated then, because currently, you'd end up with 4 rows per id based on the existing join if you had two records per id in each table. Maybe you're after a full outer join based on id and sourcecolumn or something?

Comment: For example I need to compare 2 ACCOUNTS table from 2 differenct enviroment, so I will have for example:
Account1 ID:1 
But I need to connect it with eg. table Orders with:
PK:1  FK:1 Product:Banana
PK:2  FK1  Product:Mobilephone

And table from second enviroment: 
Accounts2 ID:1 
table Orders with:
PK:1  FK:1 Order:Banana
PK:2  FK1  Order:Mobilephone

And now When I join account with order I will get:
1   Banana
1   Mobilephone

and sometimes (depends on oracle...) when I join account2 with order I will get:

1  Mobilephone
1  Banana

Comment: So for procedure that records are not same... All what I have to do is somehow order that data... But I have no idea how

Comment: Please update your question to add in the data in your tables 1 and 2, along with what you're expecting the output to be. That way, we stand a better chance of being able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for that, but how does that extra info tie in with the query in your original post?

Comment: Hmm I don' get it, Ok guys, I will try to handle with that my myself (I don't know how to explain that..). Thanks a lot for help! : ) If I will not find a solution then probably I will open a new thread. Thanks again! : )

Comment: I'd really like to help you, but I can't see the data and tables/views that you're working with. I was hoping you'd add some sample data that you'd see in table1 and table2 (regardless of whether they're tables or views), so that we could set up our own tables to match and run the query against. If you can do that, we should be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting indicates that this statement is returning more than one row

```
execute immediate 'select '||v_sourcetable||'.'||v_sourcecolumn||','||v_targettable||'.'||v_targetcolumn||' from '||v_sourcetable||','||v_targettable||' where '||
v_sourcetable||'.'||v_sourcepkcolumn||'='||v_targettable||'.'||v_targetfkcolumn into v_zmienna,v_zmienna2;
```

You have more than one way to fix that, depending on your goal you may choose.

My reccomended method would be to change the approach a little bit.  Instead of selecting into a set of variables, comparing them and doing different things depending on the variables, you can use a different method.  First, insert into table3 all the rows where your dynamic condition is met.  Then, insert into table3 all the rows where your dynamic condition is not met.  This would be something like this:

```
execute immediate 'insert into table3 values ('||v_random_number||','||v_sourcecolumn||','||v_sourcepkcolumn||','||v_zmienna||',1,'||v_targetcolumn||','||v_targetpkcolumn||','||v_zmienna2||',timestamp,'||v_verificationdefid||') ' ||
' select '||v_sourcetable||'.'||v_sourcecolumn||','||v_targettable||'.'||v_targetcolumn||' from '||v_sourcetable||','||v_targettable||' where '||
v_sourcetable||'.'||v_sourcepkcolumn||'='||v_targettable||'.'||v_targetfkcolumn );

execute immediate 'insert into table3 values ('||v_random_number||','||v_sourcepkcolumn||','||v_zmienna||',0,'||v_targetcolumn||','||v_targetpkcolumn||','||v_zmienna2||',timestamp,'||v_verificationdefid||' ||
' select '||v_sourcetable||'.'||v_sourcecolumn||','||v_targettable||'.'||v_targetcolumn||' from '||v_sourcetable||','||v_targettable||' where '||
v_sourcetable||'.'||v_sourcepkcolumn||'<>'||v_targettable||'.'||v_targetfkcolumn );
```

Your second option would be to do it basically the same way as before, but use cursors on the dynamic part as well as on the fixed part.  I'm not going to try to create the source code for that, but it would mean you need to create a cursor for the dynamic select query and do the "if" part inside the cursor loop

Comment: There is some other occur. For example tables defined in table1,table2 after join return 2 reords with same ID but in different order. For example ID:1 , 'Smth' , 1 ,'Smthelse' , and sourcetable: ID: 1: 'Smthelse, 1:'Smth', and after comparing I got status 0 which mean that records are not the same but it is not true. I can't put order by into (insert into statement) - is there any other solution to handle with that?

Comment: @maciek2791: I'm not sure what you are referring to, but it sounds to me that you have two rows in your source table with the same ID (1) but different values (Smth vs Smthelse). That means that your ID is not a primary key in that table. If you have a constraint on table3 that requires the source table to have ID as primary key, that won't work.  I don't quite understand the business problem at hand here, maybe you could describe that to make it possible to answer better